# Record file error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, record

I am using Delphi 2007 and I am trying to make record type file. In Delphi 7 there were no problems for me.

```
Type
Kompiuteris = record
...
end;
Failas = file of Kompiuteris;
```

But in Delphi 2007 I get problem. Error says that: Type "Kompiuteris" needs finalization. So, what is wrong?

Comment: Please show us what ... really is.

Comment: There is lots of strings. Now I get the probelm and going to solve it

Comment: Posting a record definition as '...' and then saying the record definition has problems is not helpful. In the future, post the actual definition of the code causing the issue, and include the version of Delphi you're using (as different versions have different features), and you'll stand a much better chance of getting help. You got very lucky this time that the error message was clear enough for @glob to be able to help so quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_finit_in_file_xml.html):

> Certain types are treated specially by the compiler on an internal basis in that they must be correctly finalized to release any resources that they might currently own. Because the compiler cannot determine what type is actually stored in a record's variant section at runtime, it is not possible to guarantee that these special data types are correctly finalized.
>
> String is one of those data types which need finalization, and as such they cannot be stored in a File type.

Comment: Yes. You would get the same error in *all* Delphi versions greater than or equal to 2. Perhaps you turned off the "long strings" compiler option.

Comment: @gedO: Look at {$H+}, {$H-} compiler directives.

You always use a ShortString in a record and write it to a file.

    type
      TRec = record
        Name: ShortString;
        Age: Integer;
      end;
      fRec = file of TRec;

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for ShortString, but were are {$H+}, {$H-} compiler directives? I am just begginer :)

Comment: Ged, please consider asking a new question: *How do I control the "long strings" compiler option?* There are several ways, and it's cumbersome to explain in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set record string fields sizing

as example :

if you have field in record called name

```
Type
Kompiuteris = record
   name :String[255] ; // Works fine
end;
```